# Iterate between List and Dictionary, handle with no found elements

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, iteration

Good evening, I'm sorry if there is already something similar to my question, but I couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to deal with values ​​that don't exist in an iteration between the items in a list and the keys in a dictionary.

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dicionario = {"1": {"x": 77.25, "y": 116.330078125},
              "2": {"x": 88.25, "y": 126.330078125},
              "3": {"x": 99.25, "y": 136.330078125}}
novo_dicionario = {}

for item in lista:
    for key, value in dicionario.items():
        if str(item) == key:
            for v in value.items():
                if v[0] in list(novo_dicionario.keys()):
                    novo_dicionario[v[0]].append(v[1])
                else:
                    novo_dicionario[v[0]] = [v[1]]
```

Resulting in:

```
{'x': [77.25, 88.25, 99.25], 'y': [116.330078125, 126.330078125, 136.330078125]}
```

As you can see, "1, 2, 3" exists as a key in the dictionary. But "4 and 5" does not. So in this case, I'd like my result to handle this exception and look like this:

```
{'x': [77.25, 88.25, 99.25, 0.00, 0.00], 'y': [116.330078125, 126.330078125, 136.330078125, 0.00, 0.00]}
```

And as the list grew and was not found as a key in the dictionary, "0.00" was added in the respective amount.

This is what I tried:

```
for item in lista:
    for key, value in dicionario.items():
        for v in value.items():
            if str(item) == key:
                if v[0] in list(novo_dicionario.keys()):
                    novo_dicionario[v[0]].append(v[1])
                else:
                    novo_dicionario[v[0]] = [v[1]]

            else:
                for v in value.items():
                    if v[0] in list(novo_dicionario.keys()):
                        novo_dicionario[v[0]].append(0.00)
                    else:
                        novo_dicionario[v[0]] = [0.00]
```

But this piece of code adds a lot of 0.00 and not only for each item.

Comment: I feel like this could be simplified by a lot through the use of defaultdict. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/defaultdict-in-python/ dictonario default value would be {"x":0.00, "y":0.00} and novo_dictario default value would be []. This way entire problem would be a simple for loop over list and than taking elements from dicts and adding to novo_dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve it using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key in lista:
    if str(key) in dicionario:
        adict = dicionario[str(key)]
        result['x'].append(adict['x'])
        result['y'].append(adict['y'])
    else:
        result['x'].append(0.00)
        result['y'].append(0.00)

print(dict(result))
```

**Output:**

```
{'x': [77.25, 88.25, 99.25, 0.0, 0.0], 'y': [116.330078125, 126.330078125, 136.330078125, 0.0, 0.0]}
```

Comment: Can be further simplified with `dictonario = defaultdict(lambda: {"x":0.00, "y":0.00})` and `for item in lista:
    val = dictonario[str(item)]
    for v in val.items():
        novo_dicionario[v[0]].append(v[1])`

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get the keys present in each sub-dictionary using set intersection.

```
from functools import reduce

keys = reduce(set.intersection, (set(d.keys()) for d in dicionario.values()))
# => {'y', 'x'}
```

Now we can write a dictionary comprehension that makes use of `dict.get` to provide default fallbacks for a missing key scenario.

```
{k: [dicionario.get(str(i), {}).get(k, 0.00) for i in lista] for k in keys}
# => {'y': [116.330078125, 126.330078125, 136.330078125, 0.0, 0.0], 'x': [77.25, 88.25, 99.25, 0.0, 0.0]}
```